# PHP Yii2 TabsX::widget превратить в select / или из ul li сделать select на css

Tags: php, css, yii2, вёрстка, select

Есть кусок кода на PHP Yii2.
Я делаю адаптив под мобильную версию.
**Как вариант** ->"Возможно кто-то знает как ul li можно превратить в подобие select чистым css и не заморачиваться с кодом ниже".

```js
<?
$items = [
    
    [
        'label'=>'<i class="fas fa-home fas-hidden"></i>'.Yii::t('app', 'Resident of Ireland'),
        'content'=>$html,
        'active'=>true,
        'linkOptions'=>['data-url'=>Url::to(['/package/tabs?tab=1'])]
    ],
    [
        'label'=>'<i class="fas fa-user fas-hidden"></i>'.Yii::t('app', 'Resident of European countries'),
        'content'=>$html,
        'linkOptions'=>['data-url'=>Url::to(['/package/tabs?tab=2'])]
    ],
    [
        'label'=>'<i class="fas fa-user fas-hidden"></i>'.Yii::t('app', 'Resident of non-European countries'),
        'content'=>$html,
        'linkOptions'=>['data-url'=>Url::to(['/package/tabs?tab=3'])]
    ],
]; 

?>

<?= 
  TabsX::widget([
      'items'=>$items,
      'position'=>TabsX::POS_ABOVE,
      'encodeLabels'=>false
  ]);
?>
```

выводит его так

```html
<ul id="w0" class="nav nav-tabs hidden-print" data-krajee-tabsx="tabsX_00000000" role="tablist">
  <li class="active"><a href="#w0-tab0" data-url="/ru-ru/package/tabs?tab=1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="w0-tab0"><i class="fas fa-home fas-hidden"></i>Resident of Ireland</a></li>
  <li><a href="#w0-tab1" data-url="/ru-ru/package/tabs?tab=2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="w0-tab1"><i class="fas fa-user fas-hidden"></i>Resident of European countries</a></li>
  <li><a href="#w0-tab2" data-url="/ru-ru/package/tabs?tab=3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="w0-tab2"><i class="fas fa-user fas-hidden"></i>Resident of non-European countries</a></li>
</ul>
```

Плюс таблица в самом widget.

На десктопе все хорошо, но в мобильной версии так не подходит, мне нужно превратить ul > li примерно в такое

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="tab" onChange="CityChange()">
  <option value="tab_1">Choose</option>
  <option value="tab_1">Resident of Ireland</option>
  <option value="tab_2">Resident of European countries</option>
  <option value="tab_3">Resident of non-European countries</option>
</select>

<div id="tab_1" style="display: none">Resident of Ireland</div>
<div id="tab_2" style="display: none">Resident of European countrie</div>
<div id="tab_3" style="display: none">Resident of non-European countries</div>
<div id="adress"></div>
```

Я не могу понять как привязать

```js
'linkOptions' => ['data-url' => Url::to(['/package/tabs?tab=1'])]
'linkOptions' => ['data-url' => Url::to(['/package/tabs?tab=2'])]
'linkOptions' => ['data-url' => Url::to(['/package/tabs?tab=3'])]
```

к select

```html
<div id="tab_1" style="display: none">Resident of Ireland</div>
<div id="tab_2" style="display: none">Resident of European countrie</div>
<div id="tab_3" style="display: none">Resident of non-European countries</div>
```

Может кто-то сталкивался с таким?

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос выпадающим списком!

```js
var text = document.getElementById("ul"),
  firstParagraph = text.firstElementChild;
var p = document.createElement("li");
p.innerHTML = "Choose region";
text.insertBefore(p, firstParagraph);

$('ul li:first').addClass('init');

$("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
  $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
});

var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
  allOptions.removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
  allOptions.toggle();
});
```

```css
ul {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  z-index: 2;
}

ul li:not(.init) {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

ul li:not(.init):hover,
ul li .selected:not(.init) {
  background: #09f;
}

ul li .init {
  cursor: pointer;
}

a#submit {
  z-index: 1;
}

li a {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.init {
  text-align: left;
  color: #bb9d54;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```